# How do I make execute with PDO output a string rather than a single-element array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I want to select a field in my mysql database containing values separated by commas (let´s say it´s "dd,bb,ee"), so that these can be exploded and turned into an array.
However, if trying to do this:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT contacts FROM Users WHERE username = ?");
$sql->execute($usernametmp);
$oldcontacts = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string 
given in /.../.../.../.../.../....php
```

on the execute line, whereas if I do the following:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT contacts FROM Users WHERE username = ?");
$sql->execute(array($usernametmp));
$oldcontacts = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

it works, but with the db entry coming out as one array element containing "dd,bb,ee", where it´ll need to be a string in order for me to use explode on it with the comma as a delimiter.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need a placeholder per value. CSV columns aren't good DB design. Is `$usernametmp` an array or string?

Comment: You could use `bindValue` to assign `$usernametmp`, but you would get the same result as passing in a one element array like in your last example. And `FETCH_COLUMN` should return the value from the first column of the first row, not an array. The two have no relation. Passing in a single element array doesn't make your `FETCH_COLUMN` output wrapped in an array. If you did a `var_dump($oldcontacts);` on the line right after you assign it, it should just be the value from the first row and contacts column.

Comment: @chris85 $usernametmp is just a string which I get from
$usernametmp = $_GET["usernametmp"];
The one question mark is the one placeholder needed.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn so what do you suggest I should do? Sorry, it´s not clear to me if that´s in your answer.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the code as written above should work exactly as you describe you want it. Was suggesting you `var_dump($oldcontacts` to verify that `fetch` with `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` doesn't return an array as you say it does.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn: Argh, my bad. I was looking at the wrong line. I´ll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the PDO `fetch` function returns an array, not a scalar, even if the row contains a single column.

(I'm not at all familiar with the `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` style with the `fetch` function.  Is that documented somewhere? I think that style can be used with the `fetchAll` function. But that will still return an array.)

The PDO `fetchColumn` function will return a scalar, rather than an array.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

---

(And passing bind parameters into the `execute` is separate unrelated issue.)

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` will work with `fetch` as well as `fetchAll`, although it isn't listed among the fetch style constants in the `fetch` documentation. It _should_ fetch a single scalar value. (I don't think that's documented anywhere. Just based on my observations.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Thanks. I'm just a little surprised that actually works.I thought `fetch` always returned an array. it seems odd that it would return a scalar when called using an undocumented fetch style. I'm not saying it doesn't work.  I'm just saying that I'm not familiar with that usage of the `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` style with the PDO `fetch` function. I've only seen that style used with the `fetchAll` function.

Comment: Yeah, I mainly have too. Actually my experience with it working in `fetch` was only because of a time that I used it accidentally and ended up debugging sort of the opposite of this question. Although I suppose most of the `fetchSomething` type functions are just shortcuts for `fetch(PDO::FETCH_SOMETHING)`.